# Grails: log stacktrace to stdout

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

When I launch my grails application, I get the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: stacktrace.log (Permission denied)

I know this can be solved by chowning some files/directories or by changing the file the logs go to, but I don't want this: I just want stracktraces to be logged to the stdout.

The [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/conf.html) states:

> For example if you prefer full stack traces to go to the console, add
>   this entry:
>
> error stdout: "StackTrace"

However: it also states:

> This won't stop Grails from attempting to create the stacktrace.log
>   file - it just redirects where stack traces are written to.

And later:

> or, if you don't want to the 'stacktrace' appender at all, configure
>   it as a 'null' appender:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        'null' name: "stacktrace"
    }
}
```

I combine the 2 and get the following configuration:

```
// log4j configuration
environments {
    production {
        log4j = {
            appenders {
                console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
                // Don't use stacktrace.log
                'null' name: "stacktrace"
            }
        }

    }
}

log4j = {
    // print the stacktrace to stdout
    error stdout:"StackTrace"
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

> INFO: Deploying web application archive MyBackend.war
>
> Sep 12, 2012 4:46:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>
> SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>
> Sep 12, 2012 4:46:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>
> SEVERE: Context [/MyBackend2] startup failed due to previous errors

Admittedly, it doesn't attempt to write stacktrace.log anymore, so the Permission denied error isn't thrown anymore, but I have no clue why the app won't start becaue the only thing it logs is "Error listenerStart"

Can anyone please help me with configuring my app to just log the stacktraces to stdout?

Comment: I found out that changing the log4j properties in Config.groovy only works after the app has started up. I eventually got to see the reason for "Error listenerStart" by entering "tail -n 150 /var/log/tomcat6/localhost.2012-09-18.log" (please change the date to today if you want to see todays stacktraces)

Answer (score 13):

Grails Bug report:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2730
(contains some workarounds)

If you want stacktraces to stdout:

```
log4j = {
  appenders {
    console name:'stacktrace'
    ...
  }
...
}
```

Disable stacktrace.log:

```
log4j = {
  appenders {
    'null' name:'stacktrace'
    ...
  }
...
}
```

stacktraces to application specific log file in Tomcat logs directory

```
log4j = {
  appenders {
    rollingFile name:'stacktrace', maxFileSize:"5MB", maxBackupIndex: 10, file:"${System.getProperty('catalina.home')}/logs/${appName}_stacktrace.log", 'append':true, threshold:org.apache.log4j.Level.ALL
    ...
  }
...
}
```

kudos to this blog post: http://haxx.sinequanon.net/2008/09/grails-stacktracelog/

Comment: About "If you want stacktraces to stdout:"
Will it still try to create stacktrace.log?

About "Disable stacktrace.log:"
Does this mean I will have no way to see the stacktraces anymore? (it won't print to stdout instead)

About "stacktraces to application specific log file in Tomcat logs directory"
Thanks for including this for completion's sake :)

Comment: Cristan: yes, that's what it means. console logging won't create stacktrace.log. Tomcat logs to catalina.out by default. disabling it means that it won't do anything and you won't be able to see it.

Comment: You're right: with your first code sample, a stacktrace.log won't be created and stacktraces thrown after the app has started will indeed show up in my stdout (in my case catalina.out). Unfortunately, it doesn't help with "Error listenerStart". The stacktrace of the error which caused this ended up in /var/log/tomcat/localhost. _today_ .log. My error was a result of a missing jar file which was needed for my DataSource for the production environment. It would be nice if it were possible to configure grails that this log will be posted to the stdout as well, but I guess this is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have to deal with this:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        // Be smart if we are running in tomcat or not 
        String logDir = Environment.warDeployed ? 
                System.getProperty('catalina.home') + '/logs' : 
                'target'

        // Handle the stacktrace log correctly
        rollingFile name:'stacktrace',
                maxFileSize: "5MB",
                maxBackupIndex: 10,
                file: "${logDir}/${appName}_stacktrace.log",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "'%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n'"),
                'append': true,
                threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ALL
    }
}
```

This lets us gracefully handle being deployed as a WAR in Tomcat, as well as in development. It also has the advantage of allowing multiple grails applications to run within the same container without mushing all of their stacktrace logs together.

Inspiration for this comes from @FlareCoder's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12393628/20770), as well as from @BurtBeckwith's [mailing list post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/stacktrace-log-tt4635524.html#a4635533).