# log file not being created in tomcat

Tags: java, grails, log4j, log4j2

I intend to have a log file for my application when it is deployed to tomcat in production environment. During development I am ok seeing the logs in the intellij console.

So I created the following DSL with the above intention (took it from SO)

```
def catalinaBase = System.properties.getProperty('catalina.base')
println "This is catalinaBase: " + catalinaBase
if (!catalinaBase) catalinaBase = '.'   // just in case
def logDirectory = "${catalinaBase}/logs"

// default for all environments
log4j = { root ->
    appenders {
        rollingFile name:'stdout', file:"${logDirectory}/myapp.log".toString(), maxFileSize:'100KB'
        rollingFile name:'stacktrace', file:"${logDirectory}/myapp_stack.log".toString(), maxFileSize:'100KB'
    }

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate'
    root.level = org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN
}

// special settings with production env
environments {
    production {
        log4j = { root ->
            appenders {
                console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n")
            }
            warn       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
                    'org.springframework',
                    'org.hibernate'
            debug  'com.mypackage'
            root.level = org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `println` in the above block. I've verified that the path to the `catalina.base` is found and outputted to `catalina.out`

However, when I deploy my application - the log files aren't being created. Furthermore, my `log.info` logs are being written to `catalina.out`.

**Question**

- What more do I need to do for log files to be created when I deploy the application?
- What does `rollingFile name:'stacktrace'` do? Does it log stacktraces to a separate file? If so, is it a log4j built-in?

Comment: You are deploying production instance and in production log4j you override appenders with just `stdout` which exactly logs to the console. If you want your files created move your file appenders to `production` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate your appenders

```
environments {
    production {
        log4j = { root ->
            appenders {
                rollingFile name:'stdout', file:"${logDirectory}/myapp.log".toString(), maxFileSize:'100KB'
                rollingFile name:'stacktrace', file:"${logDirectory}/myapp_stack.log".toString(), maxFileSize:'100KB'
            }
            warn       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
                    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
                    'org.springframework',
                    'org.hibernate'
            debug  'com.mypackage'
            root.level = org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO
        }
    }
}
```

For you second question, Yes refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12393628/2048098